What are the alternatives to a value range provider to limit the search if you're using list variables in your planning entity?
I'm working from the Timefold Vehicle Routing quickstart, the main change I've added is required skills for each Visit and Vehicle skills for each vehicle.
As it stands I'm using a constraint to limit Vehicles being assigned visits for which they don't have the right skills.
I want to implement a value range provider so that only Vehicles with the correct skills can be assigned to a Visit both to avoid sending the wrong vehicles but also to narrow the search field for faster calculation.
My problem is, I'm not sure how to go about this as Vehicles use a planning list variable of their assigned visits. From my understanding of the docs you can't use a value range provider with a planning list variable. Is there any way to make this work either in the Vehicle entity or from the Visit entity? And if not what other options are there?
I've tried looking through the docs and thought the answer might be changing to using chained variables but I wasn't sure how to implement it in the vehicle routing example

What you are looking for is filtered selection. For list variables, filtered selection currently can only be configured for Local Search (see this GitHub discussion for details). This issue tracks configuring move selectors (and thus, filtered selection) for Construction Heuristic.
So what I would recommend is:

Have constraints in your ConstraintProvider that makes sure the Vehicle's skills matches the Visit's required skills. This is so Construction Heuristic will not assign visits to vehicles that don't have the required skills.

Configure filtered selection for Local Search in the SolverConfig, which will cause Local Search to only assign visits to vehicles with the required skills.


<solver xmlns="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver https://timefold.ai/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
  <!-- ... -->
  <constructionHeuristic />
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <listChangeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>...Filter</filterClass>
          <!-- ... -->
      </listChangeMoveSelector>
      <!-- ... -->
    </unionMoveSelector>
  </localSearch>
</solver>

